# Why is degree of freedom for SSR equal to p - 1 for linear regresion

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

Why is that $SSR=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( \hat{y}_i-\bar{y} \right )^2$ have p-1 degrees of freedom? Where p is the number of parameters.

Comment: Might be related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/294789/268072

Answer (score -1):

[Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)) on the topic of degrees of freedom, to quote:

> In statistics, the number of degrees of freedom is the number of values in the final calculation of a statistic that are free to vary.[1]

which is short and also a bit vague, followed by:

> The number of independent ways by which a dynamic system can move, without violating any constraint imposed on it, is called number of degrees of freedom. In other words, the number of degrees of freedom can be defined as the minimum number of independent coordinates that can specify the position of the system completely.
>
> Estimates of statistical parameters can be based upon different amounts of information or data. The number of independent pieces of information that go into the estimate of a parameter are called the degrees of freedom. In general, the degrees of freedom of an estimate of a parameter are equal to the number of independent scores that go into the estimate minus the number of parameters used as intermediate steps in the estimation of the parameter itself (most of the time the sample variance has N − 1 degrees of freedom, since it is computed from N random scores minus the only 1 parameter estimated as intermediate step, which is the sample mean).[2]

Also, a statement relating to the dimension of, for example, a vector space:

> Mathematically, degrees of freedom is the number of dimensions of the domain of a random vector, or essentially the number of "free" components (how many components need to be known before the vector is fully determined).

And finally, an excellent point:

> While introductory textbooks may introduce degrees of freedom as distribution parameters or through hypothesis testing, it is the underlying geometry that defines degrees of freedom, and is critical to a proper understanding of the concept.